# Populate DropDown List in MVC App that Consumes a Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have a simple MVC app that is consuming a web api via REST. The controller in the MVC app makes http calls to the web api to populate views within the MVC app with razor syntax.

I am trying to figure out how to populate a drop down list on one of the 'create' actions. I'm currently just using the scaffolded page:

```
@model ComicBookInventory.Shared.ComicBookWithAuthorsAndCharactersViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CreateComicBook";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>CreateComicBook</h1>

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="CreateComicBook">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="IsRead" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsRead)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DateRead" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DateRead" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DateRead" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Rating" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Rating" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Rating" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Genre" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Genre" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Genre" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CoverUrl" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CoverUrl" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CoverUrl" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
}
}
```

Which gets populated from this action in the controller:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateComicBook(ComicBookWithAuthorsAndCharactersViewModel model)
        {
            string uri = $"https://localhost:5001/api/comicbook/add-book/";
            HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(
                    name: "ComicBookInventory.Api");

            var postTask = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<ComicBookWithAuthorsAndCharactersViewModel>(uri, model);

            if (postTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("GetAllComics");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(model);
            }
        }
```

Here is the view model definition:

```
namespace ComicBookInventory.Shared
{
    public class ComicBookWithAuthorsAndCharactersViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsRead { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateRead { get; set; }
        public int? Rating { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public string? CoverUrl { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Navigation properties
        /// </summary>
        /// a book can have many authors
        public ICollection<string>? AuthorNames { get; set; }
        public ICollection<string>? CharacterNames { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My question is, I want to add a drop down checklist to the view, so that when I am creating a comic book, I can select Authors that currently exist in the database. The same for characters.

Here is the entire code base in case anyone is interested: https://github.com/rnemeth90/ComicBookInventoryApp

I normally try and figure things out on my own (I'm relatively new to EF Core, and have very little experience with many-to-many relationships in EF core). I have tried various things and struggled with this for most of my weekend. I feel like this should be relatively simple but cannot figure it out. Please help.

Comment: you have trouble to add a drop down selector in your page? or you don't know how to query the existing `AuthorNames` in your database?

Comment: I was having trouble adding a drop-down. But I have since figured that out. The problem I have now is the drop-down is returning the Id (as a string), rather than the 'FullName' of the entity. I need it to return the FullName (string), not the Id. Though I'm not sure how to change this. Here is the relevant portion of the view:

https://github.com/rnemeth90/ComicBookInventoryApp/blob/main/src/ComicBookInventory.Web/Views/ComicBook/CreateComicBook.cshtml#:~:text=%3C/div%3E-,%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22form%2Dgroup%22%3E,-%40Html.LabelFor(model%20%3D%3E%20model.AuthorNames

Comment: I post a sample below about using DropDownList and submit the selected value, you may check it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Code, I noticed that you used `@Html.DropDownList` to realzie the selector element, and using form submit to handle the data. So I did a test in my side:

```
@{
   List<SelectListItem> listItems= new List<SelectListItem>();
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
      Text = "Exemplo1",
      Value = "Exemplo1_v"
    });
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Exemplo2",
        Value = "Exemplo2_v",
        Selected = true
    });
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Exemplo3",
        Value = "Exemplo3_v"
    });
}

<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-group">
        AuthorNames
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Author, listItems, "-- Select author --")
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

My model contains a `public string? Author { get; set; }` property, and when I click the submit button, the select value will be submitted, so when you want to pass the `FullName` to your controller, you need to set it as the `Value` of the `SelectListItem`.

[image]